# How to capture jquery datepicker input in php validation script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a demo here:  http://hane-content.com/datepick/

I have two fields, name and date.  Jquery Datepicker is attached to the date field.  I can fill out the name field, select a random date, and hit submit.  However, when the form data is processed through email.php, an error comes back saying that the date has not been filled out, like the date field is empty.  I'm a beginner.

How do you get around this?
 
**email.php**

```
<?php
// email.php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

if (empty($_POST['datoa']))
    $errors['dateoa'] = 'Date is required.';

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

    // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
    // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: **typo** -'i'll let you find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelled if `dateoa` wrong... Your code

```
(empty($_POST['datoa']))
```

Should be:

```
(empty($_POST['dateoa']))
```

(Or change the inputs name in the HTML-form).

Comment: lol! I apologize for wasting your time on this, to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as Dagon said, typo.

```
if (empty($_POST['datoa']))
```

should be

```
if (empty($_POST['dateoa']))
```